# Convert a JSON from one format to another?

Tags: java, json

I have a stream formatted In json, I want to transform It into another format in order to match it with another application's input.
for example:

```
{
  "id": "133880733349264", 
  "feed": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "message", 
        "created_time": "2013-03-16T12:12:10+0000", 
        "id": "133880733349264_477856435618357",
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "message": "message", 
              "id": "133880733349", 

            }
      ]
  }
}
```

needs to be: 
    {

```
  "feed": {

        "identifier": "133880733349264"   
        "message": "message", 
        "created_time": "2013-03-16T12:12:10+0000", 
        "id": "133880733349264_477856435618357",
       },
  "comments": {
             "message": "message", 
             "id": "133880733349", 
             "message_id":"133880733349264"
          }
}
```

any ideas or patterns on how to use it?

Comment: Can you please provide more information. Your question doesn't really give us anything to go by. (Formatted) code examples should be a minimum. Also any specific error messages might be helpful. For more info read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It is hardly rocket science.

1. Open input file.
2. Read / parse JSON from file using a JSON library.
3. Convert in-memory data structure to new structure.
4. Open output file
5. Unparse in-memory data structure to file using JSON library.

The details of the conversion will depend on your application, and on the nature of the JSON library (or bindings) that you use.  If you want to see what is available, visit http://www.json.org.

---

The other alternative would be to use a JSLT engine ... that's "XSLT for JSON" more or less.

I found a few Google hits for this ... once I convinced Google that I *really do mean JSLT* not JSTL.  But interestingly, all SO questions that mention JSLT seem to actually be misspellings of JSTL.  (That rings some warning bells for me about this approach ...)

Comment: I'm quite sure It Is not rocket sience :)
I was wondering If using some kind of parser to do the job